# Jest passing variables to tests

Tags: node.js, jestjs, integration-testing

I have a variable that is needed by various test suites. Rather than initialising in every suite, I have decided to have one test file with a `beforeAll` which initialises the variable and split the tests in suite files, which basically export the tests.

For the sake of simplicity let's assume that my test file (the only one `jest` calls) is like this:

```js
import { foobar } from './foobar'

let foo

beforeAll(() => {
  foo = 'bar'
})

describe('foo is bar', () => {
  foobar(foo)
})
```

and one of my test suite file is like this:

```js
export const foobar = (foo) => {
  it('should be defined', () => expect(foo).toBeDefined())
  it('should be bar', () => expect(foo).toMatch('bar'))
}
```

It does not work. `foo` is always `undefined` and the tests fail.

```sh
foo is bar
    ✕ should be defined (3 ms)
    ✕ should be bar
```

What am I missing? I might be having a brain fart day, so excuse me if I am being silly.

Edit (@Estus Flask)

If I define only the check in the imported `foobar` file like so:

```js
export const foobar = (foo) => expect(foo).toBeDefined()
```

and I modify the test file like so:

```js
import { foobar } from './foobar'

let foo

beforeAll(() => {
  foo = 'bar'
})

describe('foo is bar', () => {
  it('should be defined', () => foobar(foo))
})
```

It works:

```sh
foo is bar
  ✓ should be defined (2 ms)
```

So, how is Jest organising the different processes? And also yes, I could put the parameter in the global namespace, but I would like to avoid doing so.

Comment: It's unclear how these files are related, and this is most likely where the problem is. `foo` variable is local to test suite (file) where it's defined. It should be defined as a global in order to be used in imported `foobar`. It cannot be accessed neither as a local nor global in other test suites because they run in different processes.

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks, check my edits to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Rather than passing `foo` to the `foobar` function, I am exporting it and then importing it where needed.

So, my test file looks like this (with exported `foo`)

```js
import { foobar } from './foobar'

export let foo

beforeAll(() => {
  foo = 'bar'
})

describe('foo is bar', () => {
  foobar()
})
```

and my test suite file looks like this:

```js
import { foo } from './foo.test'

export const foobar = () => {
  it('should be defined', () => expect(foo).toBeDefined())
  it('should be bar', () => expect(foo).toMatch('bar'))
}
```

Now everything passes:

```sh
foo is bar
  ✓ should be defined (1 ms)
  ✓ should be bar
```